# Transform RGB image to *look like* Infrared

Tags: image, image-processing, conv-neural-network

Context: I'm trying to improve a pose estimation model so that it works better when my camera is in Infrared mode. Unfortunately I only have RGB images to train on.

I realize that you can't convert RGB to IR directly, but my hypothesis is that converting the RGB images to look more like IR, and then training on a dataset of combined RGB and IR images, will lead to better performance.

Are there any libraries that have tried to implement a function like this? I'm essentially looking for a function that something like this ("IR effect") - http://funny.pho.to/infrared/

Comment: That doesn't look like IR at all, it looks like reduced saturation. That's easy to do. Convert RGB to HSV or similar, multiply S channel by a small value such as 0.1, then convert back to RGB.

Comment: What type of IR are you looking for? Near IR or real IR? Near IR is wavelengths close to red light, it basically looks like a monochromatic light, but some surfaces reflect more or less that what you'd expect from knowing how they reflect red light. A real IR camera works at wavelengths where emitted radiation is much more important than reflected radiation, and makes e.g. A face be way brighter than clothes or hair. You can measure temperature with it.

Comment: there is no such thing as "real IR" @CrisLuengo

Comment: @Piglet: I meant to put it in quotes. What's the official name or long-wavelength infrared?

Comment: @CrisLuengo There are various specifications, each giving different names and slightly different spectra. According to ISO 20473 thermal imaging is visualizing the mid-infrared spectrum. Others call it IR-B and others define various sub-ranges within mid-infrared. but as his camera has an "infrared mode" it is unlikely that he's referring to thermal imaging. so only NIR / IR-A is relevant here.

Comment: I'm not sure what type of IR I'm looking for but I can explain what camera I use and how the images turn out. The camera is IR cut, meaning it has a mechanical IR filter. When there's no light, the IR filter gets removed. The images look grayscale. I don't believe the sensor is filtering out visible light explicitly.